# Placing fencepost close to house?

Tags: fence, post

I am installing a privacy fence that will go right up against my house.  I began digging a post hole that is about 6 inches away from my house, but about 20 inches down, I hit a bunch of cement which I assume is part of the foundation.

What would be the proper way to get my fence right up against my house?  Would I be ok to just place the post 20 inches down as long as I cement it in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use the strength of your wall, it will be quite strong to butt against the house, I would dig up to the cement foundations, then butt your post against the wall. About 3/4 the way up, just fix the post to the wall. (if the wall is cement you can use a rawl bolt, otherwise a nice threaded bolt will do the trick. You will not need anything too over the top, since the forces will mostly be from side to side (i.e there will not be too many pull forces that would pull the pin out. 
If you would like more specifics, you would need to elaborate the shape and material of the post as well as the wall.

Comment: Agree that lagging to the house is a good plan. Depending on local tradition, some folks will set sheet aluminum flashing between the post and the house. If your have a gate hinging from that post, you should use more substantial fastening to the wall.

Comment: I've heard it's bad to connect the fence directly to the house because it requires you to put holes in the siding and also because the house and the fence "swell and shrink" at the same time which an cause problems.  Do you know if these are things I should be worried about?

Comment: @Brh - yes. this is a consideration. however there is no reason why they dont expand together. ( normally not a problem) but yes. if you go Wall -- Fence -- Wall with no gates (or gaps).. then possible issue...

Answer (score 0):

I'd move the post a bit further from the house, until the foundation is no longer in the way of your hole.

Fastening the fence to the house is not a good idea.

Comment: So if the last fence post is 2 feet from the house, how to I fence that gap?

Comment: It shouldn't end up that far from the house.  If you fasten to the house, you could end up with water penetration issues. You'll also curse yourself for doing it, if you ever decide to re-side the house.

Comment: It might be worth reading through the answers to [This question](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/4765/33).

Comment: If your last post was 2' away, it would be easy enough to make a bit of fence structure that leans against your house. That said, however, I respectfully disagree with the "don't put a hole in your siding" argument. First, I can't imagine how you'd see differential movement between the post/house and tearing of the siding. Second, there are plenty of other holes in houses (think dryer vents, tv cables, hose bibs, etc) that are perfectly well sealed with judicious use of silicone. And finally, if you were re-siding your house, removing 2-4 lags and leaning the post away would be easy.